# Find N best subset of quotations

Tags: algorithms, subset-sum

I am faced with the following problem;

We are provided cost quotations for shipping cost per packet by various shipping companies, let's call these quotations $Q_1 ... Q_k$.
Each Quotation is a $M \times N$ matrix with weights categories of packets along one axis and size categories along the other axis.
We are provided with a list of packets as well with respective weights and sizes such that we can convert the packages to be shipped into a 2d matrix of size $M \times N$ as well based on categorization of each packet and each cell shall contain the relevant number of packets in that weight+size category. Let's call this matrix $P$.

The total shipping cost for all the packets should we chose a shipping company '$i$' is sum of ( $Q_i \times P$ ) where '$\times$' is the element-wise multiplication of the two matrices.

We are required to find a subset of size '$w$' shipping companies (or quotations) such that the overall shipping cost is minimum.

I understand that a brute force algorithm trying out all combinations is not going to work due to the explosion of the number of combinations as '$w$' starts to increase. Moreover, I have also convinced myself that I can not iteratively build out a solution by first selecting two best quotations, merging them into one and then continue to add one more till I reach '$w$'.

Can someone help me find the relevant class of problems and suggest a solution?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. If you can add as many shipping companies as you want to $w$, then you just need to find the $Q_i$ with the cheapest price for each of the $m \cdot n$ different types of packages. That's a $m \cdot n \cdot k$ time solution. Am I missing a some requirement for the solution?

Comment: 'w' is a number which represents the number of shipping companies you can add to the solution set. This number is an input for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is $\textrm{NP}$-hard by a reduction from (the decision version of) set-cover: given an integer $k$, a set of items $I = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ and a collection $S = \{S_1, \dots, S_m \} \subseteq 2^I$ of subsets of $I$, decide whether there is a subset $C$ of $S$ such that $|C| \le k$ and $\bigcup_{S_j \in C} S_j = I$.

Given an instance of set-cover, we can reduce it to your problem as follows:

- There are $n$ packages to be shipped. Each package has a unique combination of weight class and category. For simplicity you can think of all the packages being in same category but having different weight classes. I will denote by $W_i$ the weight class of the $i$-th package.
- There are $m$ shipping companies. The $j$-th shipping company ships a package of weight class $W_i$, with $x_i \in S_j$, for a cost of $\varepsilon < \frac{1}{n}$ and a package of weight class $W_i$, $x_i \not\in S_j$, for a cost of $1$.
- Pick $w = k$.

There is a set-cover of size at most $k$ iff the cost for shipping all the packages using at most $w$ companies is at most $\varepsilon n < 1$.

Indeed, given a set-cover $C = \{ S_{j_1}, \dots, S_{j_\ell} \}$ of size $\ell < k$ we know that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\ell S_{j_\ell} = I$, i.e., if we select the $j_1$-th, $j_2$-th, $\dots$, and $j_\ell$-th shipping companies, we can send each of the $n$ packages at a cost of $\varepsilon$.

On the other hand, if there is a way to send all the packages using at most $w$ shipping companies with a cost of at most $\varepsilon n < 1$ then, for each of the $n$ packages, there must be at least one selected company that ships it with a cost of $\varepsilon$. In other words the sets $S_j$ corresponding to the selected companies are a set-cover of size at most $w = k$.

Notice that any solution has either a cost of $\varepsilon n$ or a cost of at least $1$. Choosing $\varepsilon$ small enough shows that this problem is also inapproximable (in fact, if a shipping cost of $0$ is allowed, you can directly set $\varepsilon = 0$).